# How to specify nested custom view class?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, nested-class

**Available**
nested classes SuperView and NestedView.

```js
class SuperView : UIImageView {

    class NestedView : UIImageView {
        var text : String = "Nested View"
    }

    var text : String = "Super View"
    var nested : NestedView?

}
```

**I would like** to set for a UIImageView the property named "Custom Class Name" to value "NestedView" inside the inspector of the storyboard scene. But the Interface Builder couldn't find "NestedView" class.

[image]

Comment: My expectation, based on how nested types work elsewhere, would be that you could assign the class to `SuperView.NestedView` but interface builder does not allow this. I think this would be a great feature for namespacing small, purpose-built subviews.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At this time, I think that Interface Builder only recognizes the names of Objective-C classes. You can still make Interface Builder find a nested class with the @objc keyword:

```
class SuperView: UIView {
  @objc(SVNestedView) class NestedView: UIImageView {
  }
}
```

Then, in Interface Builder, specify that th view is of class SVNestedView. Since Objective-C isn't namespaced, you still need to pick unique names for each nested class, but at least the Swift side is properly namespaced.

Comment: Thanks, this is so handy!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Swift 3 in Xcode 8.1. Still can't see `SVNestedView` in IB

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems Xcode doesn't support showing connected `IBOutlets` for nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, an instance of an inner class is independent of any instance of the outer class. It is as if all inner classes in Swift are declared using Java's static.

I don't think this class design suits your requirement. What you need to do is, you need to create a new class *outside* your view, and create some sort of a composition. This will surely work out for you.

Here is some modification to your code:

```
class SuperView : UIImageView {
    var text : String = "Super View"
    var nested : NestedView = NestedView()
}

class NestedView : UIImageView {
    var text : String = "Nested View"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it impossible to specify an inner class in a storyboard like `SuperView.NestedView` so far. So I makes a class extended from an inner class, then specifies it in a storyboard like `SuperView_NestedView`. It works for me.

```
final class SuperView_NestedView: SuperView.NestedView {} // Specifies this class in the storyboard 
class SuperView : UIImageView {

    class NestedView : UIImageView {
        var text : String = "Nested View"
    }

    var text : String = "Super View"
    var nested : NestedView?

}
```

This view can be referred as `SuperView.NestedView` from a ViewController because `SuperView_NestedView` is extended from `SuperView.NestedView`.

```
class TheViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var nestedView: SuperView.NestedView!
```