# Use Swift inner class in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have an inner custom `UITableViewCell` class (class inside a class), I would like to use it in Interface Builder. However, it can't recognize it there.

```swift
import UIKit

class ContactListViewController: UIViewController {
    class Cell: UITableViewCell {
        @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var phone: UILabel!
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
}
```

[image: screenshot]

The configuration of above image didn't work. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: create a xib for UITableViewCell and assign the class to it and then in the UITableView, you can assign the UITableViewCell class to the prototyped cell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I created a xib for UITableViewCell, but I still can't assign an inner class to UITableViewCell on xib.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify nested custom view class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066073/how-to-specify-nested-custom-view-class)

Comment: For Swift, the proper terminology is 'nested class'.

Answer (score 24):

You need to specify objective c name for your nested class with `@objc` then use it in the Interface Builder:

```
import UIKit

class ContactListViewController: UIViewController {
    @objc(CLCell) class Cell: UITableViewCell {
        @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var phone: UILabel!
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
}
```

[image]

Comment: Caveat: you need to ensure the module is `None` as shown. Otherwise, Interface builder will try to find the class+module by its mangled name, which won't exist.